# copy a specific part of string php

Tags: php, web

How can I get a part of a string from the specific starting position to end. Like for example I want to copy `B000ROAQ30` from the given url:

> www.amazon.com/Black-Nokia-HS-47-Stereo-Headset/dp/B000ROAQ30/ref=pd_sim_hi_4

This `B000ROAQ30` part can occour anywhere in the URL like in this case:

> www.amazon.com/abc/cdfg/hij/dp/B000ROAQ30/ref=pd_sim_hi_4

How can I copy this `B000ROAQ30`?

Note `B000ROAQ30` can be different but having `B00` at the start.

Please ask questions if anything is not clear.

Comment: Please format your question - this is something you can do even if you are not profficient with English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$url = 'www.amazon.com/Black-Nokia-HS-47-Stereo-Headset/dp/B000ROAQ30/ref=pd_sim_hi_4';
preg_match('/B00[0-9A-Z]+/', $url, $matches);

$result = $matches[0];
```

`$result` in this case will be: `B000ROAQ30`. Check it here: http://ideone.com/XrjIG

Comment: Thats soo simple and coooll... Thanks

Comment: This assumes that the first instance of B00 in the URL will always be the one he's looking for and that it only has letters and capital numbers (of at least one)

Comment: @tandu: Exactly as in the question :) "_This B000ROAQ30 part can occour anywhere in the URL_", also it seems this part consists only of uppercase letters and digits, nothing more. It can be adjusted of course, but it needs to be specified what else could it contain and if its place within URL is somehow limited (eg. occurs only between slashes `/`).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming B00... is always before the last slash:

```
$rurl = strrev($url);
list(,$boo) = explode('/', $rurl);
$boo = strrev($boo);
```

Assuming you have no idea where B00 is, just that it starts with B00 and ends with a slash:

```
preg_match('@/B00.*?/@', $boo);
$boo = trim($boo[0], '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna have a look at parse_url() and pathinfo() if you wanna extract certain path parts.